# I would like to mutate the values within a specific column into a single value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct-values

[image: Image Here]

How do I cast the values that are not equal "Amsterdam" or "Berlin" or "Edinburgh" or "Stockholm" or "Amsterdam-Zuidoost" into a single value called "Other Cities"?
My data is called housingdata, my variable is called "City".

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%in%` with list of values to check :

```
cities <- c("Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Edinburgh", "Stockholm", "Amsterdam-Zuidoost")
housingdata$City[!housingdata$City %in% cities] <- 'Other Cities'
```

---

Other options include :

```
transform(housingdata, City = replace(City, !City %in% cities, 'Other Cities'))
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
housingdata %>% mutate(City = if_else(City %in% cities, City, 'Other Cities'))
```

and

```
housingdata %>%
   mutate(City = case_when(City %in% cities~ City, 
                          TRUE ~'Other Cities'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like a dplyr solution, you can use `mutate()` and `case_when`:

```
library(tidyverse)

housingdata <-
  data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L),
              City = c("Amsterdam","Berlin",
                       "Edinburgh","Stockholm","Amsterdam-Zuidoost","Chicago",
                       "Seattle")
)

housingdata_m <-
  housingdata %>% 
  mutate(Category = case_when(City %in% c("Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Edinburgh", "Stockholm", "Amsterdam-Zuidoost") ~ City,
                                          TRUE ~ "Other Cities"))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `dplyr` would be:

```
library(dplyr)
housingdata %>% 
  mutate(City = if_else(!City %in% c("Amsterdam", "Berlin", "Edinburgh", 
                                         "Stockholm", "Amsterdam-Zuidoost"), 'Other Cities', City)
```

Of course you could create a new variable or overwrite your existing `City` variable as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what the OP really wants to do is `summarize`.

```
library(dplyr)
targetcountries <- c("Amsterdam","Berlin","Edinburgh","Stockholm","Amsterdam-Zuidoost")
housingdata %>%
  mutate(Country = case_when(Country %in% targetcountries ~ Country,
                             TRUE ~ "Other")) %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarize(Value = sum(Value))
```